# ¿Cómo obtener el ultimo elemento de un JList?

Tags: java, array

Tengo una lista que la uso como contador de líneas. Al presionar <kbd>Enter</kbd> la lista aumenta por 1 valor y solo me falta hacer que al presionar <kbd>Backspace</kbd> o borrar se elimine el ultimo elemento de la lista y no se como obtener el ultimo objeto ¿Saben como hacerlo?

Este es parte de mi código:

```
int texto = 11;
int resultado = texto+1;
public void agregarvalores() {
    texto = texto + 1;
    modelolista.addElement(texto);
}
public void eliminarvalores(){
    texto = texto - 1; // la funcion que resta un numero para poder seguir sumando
    // AQUI! FALTA la funcion para eliminar el ultimo objeto de una lista
}
private void editorKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        //texto++;
        agregarvalores();
    }
    else if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE ) {
        eliminarvalores();
    }
}
```

Los valores de la tabla empiezan en el número 11. Gracias :v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eliminar el último elemento de tu `Vector` (veo que usas `addElement()` ) puedes usar el método `remove()` y a partir de la medida del arreglo calcular el indice del último elemento

```
System.out.println("Ultimo elemento: "+modelolista.get(modelolista.size()- 1));
```

Para remover el último elemento:

```
 modelolista.remove( modelolista.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvió